# How to determine the default browser with C#?

Tags: c#, windows

I have the following code in C# .NET Core Windows 10:

```
    public string getBrowser()
    {
        string browserName = "iexplore.exe";
        using (RegistryKey userChoiceKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice"))
        {
            if (userChoiceKey != null)
            {
                object progIdValue = userChoiceKey.GetValue("Progid");
                if (progIdValue != null)
                {
                    if (progIdValue.ToString().ToLower().Contains("chrome"))
                        browserName = "chrome.exe";
                    else if (progIdValue.ToString().ToLower().Contains("firefox"))
                        browserName = "firefox.exe";
                    else if (progIdValue.ToString().ToLower().Contains("opera"))
                        browserName = "opera.exe";
                }
            }
        }

        return browserName;
    }
```

The problem is that

> userChoiceKey

is always null.

I practically copy paste the path from the registry Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice

And still not working.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you creating a 32bit application (x86) or a 64bit one (x64, AnyCPU on x64 OS)?

Comment: Just an advise for the future, you shouldn't blindly copy and paste, when you look at your code it should be obvious why it doesn't work. With this line `Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"\HKEY_CURRENT_USER` you are accessing `Registry.CurrentUser` and than try to open a sub key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, there is no sub key in current user that is current user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
internal string GetSystemDefaultBrowser()
    {
        string name = string.Empty;
        RegistryKey regKey = null;

        try
        {
            var regDefault = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts\\.htm\\UserChoice", false);
            var stringDefault = regDefault.GetValue("ProgId");

            regKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(stringDefault + "\\shell\\open\\command", false);
            name = regKey.GetValue(null).ToString().ToLower().Replace("" + (char)34, "");

            if (!name.EndsWith("exe"))
                name = name.Substring(0, name.LastIndexOf(".exe") + 4);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            name = string.Format("ERROR: An exception of type: {0} occurred in method: {1} in the following module: {2}", ex.GetType(), ex.TargetSite, this.GetType());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (regKey != null)
                regKey.Close();
        }

        return name;
    }
```

Comment: As a style tip, I prefer to use `'"'.ToString()` instead of `"" + (char)34`. Doing it that way I don't have to remember 34 is a `"`